# Django models query all related objects of all instances of a class (many to many relationship)

Tags: django-models

I have the following models:

Player

- player_name (CharField)
- cards (ManyToManyField->Card)

Card

- card_name

I can easily query all the cards owned by one player, by running `Player.objects.get(id=1).cards.all()`.

But how do I retrieve all the cards of all players? I am looking for something like `Player.objects.all().cards`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you retrieve the player don't you retrieve the cards property? When you get the player with id=1 you get the cards indirectly, in the "cards" property.

Comment: Thanks @WilsonPena. Yes. for one player I get the cards property as you mention. But for all the Player instances, I do not get it. get returns a Player instance and all() returns a queryset.

Answer (score 0):

Try `iterating` through the `queryset`.

```
players = Player.objects.all()

cards = []
for player in players:
    player_cards = player.cards.all()
    cards.append(player_cards)
```

You might have to play with the syntax a little, but that should get you close